# Electron-Osx-Sign is breaking my app

Tags: electron

When I run electron-osx-sign My app no longer opens. I can see in the dock that it tries to open for a split second, then immediately closes with no error or warning. Does this have something to do with how I am signing or the entitlements?

CLI:

> sudo electron-osx-sign App.app
>   --provisioning-profile=My.provisionprofile --entitlements=parent.plist --entitlements-inherit=child.plist

Entitlements Patent:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC
> "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
> "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> <plist
> version="1.0">   <dict>
>     <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
>     <true/>
>     <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
>     <string>"my team id here".com.site.app</string>   </dict> </plist>
```

Child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```